# Unable to locate the PHPmailer library : getting a failed to open stream message

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send emails using the phpmailer library that I have downloaded manually. I have tried to follow the tutorial provided on https://alexwebdevelop.com/phpmailer-tutorial/ and I did not choose the option to use composer, since my knowledge in Composer are very limited .. Please bear with me :)

I got an src zip file that I have installed on my host's server in one of my folder as shown on the picture below:

[image]

When running the PHP script, I'm getting the following error message :

[image]

My code source 'send_mail_3.php' is installed in the folder called 'php' (web2\php)

I'm asking for support today, because I don't know where to start my investigation.

I hope this question will be understandable and useful for other users.

Thanks for your help.

Here is the contents of my send_mail_3.php:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

/* Exception class. */
require '\PHPMailer\src\Exception.php';

/* The main PHPMailer class. */
require '\PHPMailer\src\PHPMailer.php';

/* SMTP class, needed if you want to use SMTP. */
require '\PHPMailer\src\SMTP.php';

/* Create a new PHPMailer object. Passing TRUE to the constructor enables exceptions. */
$mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);

/* Open the try/catch block. */
try {
   /* Set the mail sender. */
   $mail->setFrom('myemailaddress@google.com', 'Darth Vader');

   /* Add a recipient. */
   $mail->addAddress('myemailaddress@google.com', 'Emperor');

   /* Set the subject. */
   $mail->Subject = 'Force';

   /* Set the mail message body. */
   $mail->Body = 'There is a great disturbance in the Force.';

   /* Finally send the mail. */
   $mail->send();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
   /* PHPMailer exception. */
   echo $e->errorMessage();
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
   /* PHP exception (note the backslash to select the global namespace Exception class). */
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re confusing paths and namespaces. Your `use` statements are correct, but your require paths are not. Assuming you have put PHPMailer in a folder called `PHPMailer` next to your script, it should be:

```php
/* Exception class. */
require './PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';

/* The main PHPMailer class. */
require './PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

/* SMTP class, needed if you want to use SMTP. */
require './PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

Beyond this, learn how to use composer.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are loading namespace of php mailer, so I think you just need to use full path like your `require '\PHPMailer\src\Exception.php';`. You can try following steps:

- Try to set alias for the name space

  ```
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer as Mailer;
  ```
- Require it but with alias namespace instead: `require 'Mailer\PHPMailer.php';`

Comment: No, you’re confusing namespaces and paths.

Comment: Sorry but please clarify me about that

Comment: See my answer. Generally namespace imports are orthogonal to file paths, though they often align through conventions like PSR-4.